# ssh not recognized by powershell when running from a python script

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, ssh

So this (with native window command) works:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "dir"], shell=True)
```

Running ssh from native powershell is successful

but when replacing 'dir' with 'ssh *hostname@ip*' I get the following error:

ssh.exe : The term 'ssh.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Try using the full path to the ssh program

Comment: nice try but that doesn't help, I get:
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe : The term 'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe' is not recognized as the name of 
a cmdlet, function, script file